# Rake test not working in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm trying to run Minitests in my rails library app, when I run `rake test`, I get an error saying `LoadError: cannot load such file -- rake/testtask`.

Here is my rakefile:

```
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup

require 'rake/testtask'

desc 'Test the library.'
Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << 'lib' << 'test'
  t.pattern = 'test/**/*_test.rb'
  t.verbose = true
end
```

Below is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gemspec

gem 'minitest'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'byebug', platforms: :mri
gem 'rake'
```

Comment: What do you get with `rake --version` on command line?

Comment: @nikkypx, i get `rake, version 11.2.2`

Answer (score 0):

Rake is not being loaded. Add `gem 'rake'` to your Gemfile

Comment: shouldn't rake be installed automatically? I uploaded my gemfile.

Comment: move `gem 'rake'` to the top of the Gemfile below source and try it again

Comment: Now I'm getting an error saying `gems/cliver-0.3.2/lib/cliver/dependency.rb:188: warning: instance variable @requirement not initialized`

Comment: that is a new problem